# Is there a way to resize the dimensions of multiple APNG files at once?

Tags: software-recommendation, png, resize, batch-processing

I have about 40 APNG (animated PNG) files that are each 618 by 618 pixels. I would like to convert them all at once to 408 by 408 pixels, while keeping the same animation, frame duration, transparency, etc. I found an online converter [here](https://ezgif.com/resize) that seems to do what I want, but it only allows you to convert one file at a time.